# Laplace Transform of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to find out whether there is a way to get this into the s domain? $$\mathcal{L} \left\{  1 / \log \  x\right\}$$ (1)

now I know using Laplace Tranforms I can get
$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ \log x\right\}=-\frac{1}{s}\left(\log s + \gamma\right)$$ (2)

but the reciprocal of log is causing a problem since $$\log_bc=\frac{1}{\log_cb}$$ simply changing the base.

Is there any trick one can use? I tried getting it all in terms of log but I could not get that to work.

Comment: Wolfram says that it is not representable in elementary functions

Comment: I wonder why? It looks similar to 1/t maybe  because it sort of  decays to the x axis.

Comment: @Mark Viola okay thanks, so it is impossible to solve?

Comment: @MarkViola how do you know it converges? I'm suspicious about $t = 1$.

Comment: what about over a different range say t=2 onwards?

Comment: @onepound Laplace transform needs to work on $(0..+\infty)$. Perhaps it converges in the sense of Cauchy Principle Value.
 (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cauchy_Principal_Value)

Comment: @gfauxpas It appears that you've answered your own question.  Yes, it converges as an improper integral in the sense of a.Cauchy PV.

Comment: The shape of a curve tells absolutely nothing about existence of a closed-form antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

answer is : $\exp(-1/s)$, use the Feynman integration, you will get the integral of $\dfrac {t! }{ s ^ t}$, use the Melin transform and substitute (after calculating the integral) $t = -1$

Comment: correction :)  t=  -1

Comment: Is this what you meant Tomas ? You can always edit your answer to correct your mistakes just click on the edit button.